# Jetpack Compose: change bottom nav back press behavior with Navigation Components

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

I finally started using Compose for Android and I am currently stuck at navigation. I have two questions:

**1.**
I have implemented a bottom navigation with three buttons and one of the buttons triggeres a nested navigation graph, like:

```
 HOME  ---  CONTACTS  ---  FAVOURITES 
   |            
DETAILS
```

So when I open details screen from home and switch tabs, the behavior is correct, the state and last destination in the nested graph is memorized and when I tap again on home, it keeps the state and switches back to details. However, if I am on any of the other tabs and press back, it brings me to home but it resets the state, it doesn't bring me back into details. How can I achieve that?

Navigation Bar:

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavHostController) {
BottomNavigation {
    val backStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentRoute = backStackEntry?.destination?.route

    BottomNavigationCollection.items.forEach { navItem ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
            selected = currentRoute == navItem.route,
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(navItem.route) {
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                        saveState = true
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true
                }
            },
            icon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = navItem.icon,
                    contentDescription = navItem.title
                )
            },
            label = {
                Text(text = navItem.title)
            },
        )
    }
}
```

Navigation Host:

```
@Composable
fun NavigationHost(navController: NavHostController) {
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = NavigationRoutes.Home.route,
    route = "root"
) {
    homeGraph(navController)

    composable(NavigationRoutes.Contacts.route) {
        ContactsScreen()
    }

    composable(NavigationRoutes.Favorites.route) {
        FavouritesScreen()
    }
}
```

}

Nested Home Navigation Graph:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.homeGraph(navController: NavController) {
navigation(
    startDestination = NavigationRoutes.Dashboard.route,
    route = NavigationRoutes.Home.route
) {
    composable(NavigationRoutes.Dashboard.route) {
        DashboardScreen(navController)
    }

    composable(NavigationRoutes.Details.route) {
        DetailsScreen(navController)
    }
}
```

}

**2.**
When I am back in home with the entire navigation stack clear and press back once more, naturally the app closes. How can I intercept back press and implement a "tap again to exit" confirmation feature at that point?

Comment: Hi, I am stuck at the same point regarding your question 1), did you find a solution for it?

Comment: This happens if you're navigating to a nested graph without clearing the back stack, make sure to pop the backstack ID for the intended behavior.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well. Any solution @BenjyTec or OP?

Comment: @iamnaran I'm not sure I understand how that solves 1) ? If I understand you correctly, that is what he is doing and what I am doing but when we hit the system back button, it doesn't take you to the "Home"'s back stack, it takes you to the startDestination.

Comment: @JoshuaKing I posted an answer. I resolved it using `BackHandler`. This however was on an old Compose version. I would be glad if you could report back if that still works, as I can't test it myself right now.

Comment: Yea, that technically works, however, I don't want to do that manually for all of our 50+ screens. :P I was hoping for a solution that was once for all screens. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer your first question, but for your second one: I just stumbled upon [BackHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#BackHandler(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0)). I just tried it real quick and it got called instead of closing the app, so that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using an empty [`BackHandler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#BackHandler(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0)). As your Contacts and Favorites screens do not have any nested navigation themselves, this should work in your case. The `BackHandler` will consume the back press and will prevent it from being interpreted as `popBackStack`.

```
@Composable
fun Contacts() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    
    BackHandler {
        // leave empty
    }
}
```

In the `BackHandler`, you also could place a "click twice to close app" behavior. You can try it like this:

```
@Composable
fun Contacts() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var firstPressed by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    
    BackHandler() {
        if (firstPressed) {
            val activity = (context as? Activity)
            activity?.finish()
        } else {
            firstPressed = true
            Toast.makeText(context, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            coroutineScope.launch {
                delay(2000L)  // set delay here as wished
                firstPressed = false
            }   
        }
    }
}
```